# How to load kernel modules for current hardware in init of minimal Busybox-based system

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, busybox, init

In a minimal **Busybox**-based Linux system, which commands must be invoked as part of the `init` script to ensure all kernel modules for the current hardware are loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going down the rabbit hole, assuming a minimal initramfs with some drivers built into the kernel and others present as kernel modules along with all relevant `depmod`-generated metadata, here is what I found:

Drivers built into the kernel are loaded before `/init` is invoked.

Drivers built as modules must be loaded by `/init` as follows:

- first `/sys` and `/proc` must be mounted
- then the existing hardware should be scanned and the relevant kernel modules should be loaded

The hardware scanning and module loading should normally be accomplished by a simple [`mdev -s` invokation](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#mdev).

Unfortunately that [doesn't work as it should](https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=14481). One must thereforce force this process to occur by invoking `find /sys/ -name modalias | xargs sort -u | xargs -n 1 modprobe` instead.

After that all the drivers for the current hardware (and their dependencies) will have been loaded and initialized.

Comment: That last pipeline command line doesn't make sense: neither modutils modprobe or busybox modprobe support loading a module based on a path to a modalias file in /sys.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hardware there will be some calls to **dbus** to load modules. Most of this should be automated already. I assume via  **initramfs**, **udev/mdev**, **hald** , **init-system**, and so on ...

One way to load modules manually is to call `modprobe` which will take care of all dependencies.

For example:

```
# modprobe snd_pcm
```

In my case this will load all modules needed to create sounds.

First `modprobe` will load all dependencies for `snd_hda_core`. This is cause `snd_hda_core` is part of the `snd_pcm`.

```
$ lsmod | grep ^snd_hda_core 
snd_hda_core          110592  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
```

After that all `snd_pcm` dependencies are loaded by `modprobe`.

```
$ lsmod | grep ^snd_pcm
snd_pcm               135168  10 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
```

There is a folder called `/etc/modules-load.d/` and in it are `*.conf` files to load some modules by default.
This should take care of all you need, so there is no need to write an init-script...

```
$ cat /etc/modules-load.d/local.conf 
vfio_pci
asus-wmi-sensors
tun
```

I other words: I can load all modules with just one call or one file.

**modprobe manpage ...**

> modprobe expects an up-to-date modules.dep.bin file as generated by
> the corresponding depmod utility shipped along with modprobe (see
> depmod(8)). This file lists what other modules each module needs (if
> any), and modprobe uses this to add or remove these dependencies
> automatically

**depmod manpage ...**

> Linux kernel modules can provide services (called "symbols") for other
> modules to use (using one of the EXPORT_SYMBOL variants in the code).
> If a second module uses this symbol, that second module clearly
> depends on the first module. These dependencies can get quite complex.
>
> depmod creates a list of module dependencies by reading each module
> under /lib/modules/version and determining what symbols it exports and
> what symbols it needs. By default, this list is written to
> modules.dep, and a binary hashed version named modules.dep.bin, in the
> same directory.

#####################

**Addition**

after pointing out I should explain the magic behind all this. I have to try but its a bit sketchy.

Lets take a look at one of my gpus.

The following example shows the **modalias** of my gpu and the **alias** in the module definition overlaps.

```
$ lspci
...
0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
...
$ cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/modalias
pci:v000010DEd00001B06sv00001462sd00003607bc03sc00i00
$ modinfo nvidia
...
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:        i2c-core,drm
...
```

**lspci manpage ...**

> Kernel module reporting that it is capable of handling the device

This part is a bit unknown to me and I had to guess a bit.

Anyway, cause of the information I gathered now I know two ways to setup the module depending on this information.

**first method (at boot) ...**

```
echo "alias $(cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/modalias) nvidia" >> /etc/modprobe.d/default.conf
```

**second method (runtime)...**

```
echo "0000:0b:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvidia/bind
```

The **nvidia** folder can be one of any module name, for example I could give it the **vfio-pci** folder instead.

```
echo "0000:0b:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvidia/unbind
echo "0000:0b:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/bind
```

Keep in mind this is just an example and wont work in a real environment, cause gpu modules have to be loaded at boot time only.

Comment: Please revise your answer and don't assume any distro or other setup. This question is purely about a minimal setup involving just a kernel and an initramfs containing `busybox` and an init script located at `/init` . Devices can mounted either with `devtmpfs` or `mdev` (there is no `udev` in this setup)

Comment: ok thx. maybe he uses `mdev` instead of `udev`. but this doesn't change the fact that he needs a way to load modules, like `modprobe` or `insmod`. I showed a way to load modules and pointed to the manpages of `depmod`. If he doesn't use `depmod` it will get really messy and we would need more intel on the hardware to approach this. The one and only alternative I know of is to put all modules into the initramfs

Comment: `modprobe` doesn't automatically coldplug all the current hardware and still requires someone to hardcode which modules to load. What I am interested in is the missing "glue" that will cause the system to scan all devices in /sys and then automatically call modprobe only for those that were found.

Comment: ok I updated my post, hope this will halp